# How to select users having only particular tag not another tag

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following db schema
[image: sql schema]

I need to get the fname, lname of the user who have tag name 'A' and also they should not have tag name 'B'.For example User X has both tag A, tag B, He should not be included in the result whereas if another user Y only have Tag 'A' he should be included in the result. Is this possible without sub query?Do i have to alter the schema?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: There is no schema provided. How do you expect us to suggest to `alter` schema?

Comment: Your picture is not working. Please provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can `GROUP BY` on user id and name.
- Use `HAVING` clause with `SUM()` aggregation to filter out cases.
- If a user does not have a tag 'B', `SUM(name = 'B')` will be zero, post joins.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  u.user_id, 
  u.fname, 
  u.lname 
FROM 
  user AS u 
JOIN tags AS t ON t.user_id = u.user_id 
JOIN tags_def AS td ON td.tag_id = t.tag_id 
GROUP BY 
  u.user_id, 
  u.fname, 
  u.lname 
HAVING 
  SUM(td.name = 'A') AND
  SUM(td.name = 'B') = 0
```